# Как последовательно обрабатывать ответы HttpQueryInfo?

Tags: c++, winapi, http

Делаю так:

```
//Посылаю запрос (POST):
TCHAR postHead[46] = "Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8\r\n";

HttpSendRequestA(hResourceHandle, postHead, 45, (LPVOID)"{\"action\":\"cancel\"}", 19);

//Получаю ответ:
char StatusCode[30] = "";
DWORD StatusCodeLen = sizeof(StatusCode);
HttpQueryInfo(hResourceHandle, HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE, &StatusCode, &StatusCodeLen, NULL);
StatusCode[StatusCodeLen];

//Вывожу ответ в строку статуса:
if (strcmp(StatusCode, "200") == 0) SetWindowTextA(myStatusEdit, "Исполнено");
if (strcmp(StatusCode, "202") == 0) SetWindowTextA(myStatusEdit, "Ожидание");
if (strcmp(StatusCode, "400") == 0) SetWindowTextA(myStatusEdit, "Неверные параметры");
if (strcmp(StatusCode, "404") == 0) SetWindowTextA(myStatusEdit, "Ордер не найден");
if (strcmp(StatusCode, "500") == 0) SetWindowTextA(myStatusEdit, "Ошибка сервера");
```

Мой запрос уходит и исполняется на стороне сервера без проблем и я получаю ответ.
Проблема в том, что первым приходит ответ 202 "Ожидание" и я его фиксирую, но потом должен приходить ответ 200 "Исполнено", но как его поймать и обновить статус я не понимаю.

Пробовал делать это через цикл:

```
while (strcmp(StatusCode, "202") == 0)
{
    SetWindowTextA(myStatusEdit, "Ожидание");
    HttpSendRequestA(hResourceHandle, postHead, 45, NULL, 0);
    HttpQueryInfo(hResourceHandle, HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE, &StatusCode, &StatusCodeLen, NULL);
    StatusCode[StatusCodeLen];
}
```

Но на цикле программа зависает.

Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP не поддерживает несколько ответов на один запрос: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.2.3

> 202 Accepted
>
> The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has
> not been completed.  The request might or might not eventually be
> acted upon, as it might be disallowed when processing actually takes
> place. **There is no facility for re-sending a status code from an
> asynchronous operation such as this.**

Если запрос обрабатывается асинхронно, API должен поддерживать проверку статуса через GET-запрос, например, по ID. Либо повторный запрос должен вернуть ошибку, если ID запроса дублируется. А приведенный код отправляет кучу дублирующихся запросов и зависает, скорее всего, из-за перегрузки сервера или срабатывания защиты от DOS-атаки у CDN. Как минимум, при последовательных запросах нужна пауза между ними в пару секунд, чтобы не создавать такую большую нагрузку на сеть.

Comment: да, спасибо, так и есть.